# How do I extract username and domain from an email using PHP script?

Tags: php

I'm trying to code a PHP script that is given a string with an email address that extracts the username and domain.

For example: username@domain.com -> username | domain.com

I want to take off the "@".

**I've tried using trim() but that only works at the start and at the end of a string.**

Comment: you should look into `explode()`

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$email = 'username@domain.com';

$getArray = explode("@",$email);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($getArray);

echo $getArray[0].'<br/>';
echo $getArray[1];
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was stuck to get the first word and the second one. Whenever I used the [0] or [1] it gave me only the letter.

Comment: a good answer explains their solution